# Adding estraverse library to an aurelia-cli project causes the build to fail

Tags: aurelia

I have followed the documentation's instructions regarding how to add client libraries to an aurelia-cli project. I have being able to add a couple of them including bootstrap. However, when I tried to add estraverse.js, the build failed with this log:

```
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildJavaScript'...
Finished 'buildJavaScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
Tracing app...
{ uid: 9,
 name: 'writeBundles',
 branch: false,
 error:
 { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 

open 'C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\src\package.json.js'
   at Error (native)
   at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
   at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
   at Object.exports.readFileSync (C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\file-system.js:38:13)
   at amodroTrace.fileRead (C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundled-source.js:83:31)
   at Object.context.fileRead (C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:176:18)
   at Object.context.load (C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:357:30)
   at Object.Module.load (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:9), <anonymous>:832:29)
   at Object.Module.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:9), <anonymous>:822:66)
   at Object.Module.check (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\abdulaziz\Downloads\newProject\life-code\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:9), <anonymous>:854:30)
 errno: -4058,
 code: 'ENOENT',
 syscall: 'open',
 path: 'C:\\Users\\abdulaziz\\Downloads\\newProject\\life-code\\src\\package.json.js',
 moduleTree: [ 'estraverse' ],
 fileName: 'C:/Users/abdulaziz/Downloads/newProject/life-code/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js' },
duration: [ 1, 52233832 ],
time: 1471898227440 }
```

I think it tries to load .json file but fails to do so. Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

This is my attempt :
In Aurelia.json, I added .json to plugin in the loader section:

```
"loader": {
  "type": "require",
  "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
  "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "text",
      "extensions": [
        ".html",
        ".css",
        ".json"
      ],
      "stub": true
    }
  ]
},
```

But did not work!

Comment: I agree. There needs to be more infos about addition of dependencies.

Comment: I have moved to jspm and everything worked well. aurelia-cli is still not ready to be the way to go with aurelia projects. still promising, though.

Comment: I agree. And using aurelia-bundle, my bundling was way quicker and cleaner. Sadly you need to modify the code if you want to integrate mapping between minified and original sources.